# Determine category based on quarter and results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck on a formula I am trying to build in excel.

I have 5 sales categories that a person could end up in based on the results of their quarter sales: Red, Yellow, Green, Gold, Platinum.

So if you sell X amount last quarter, based on that you are in one of those categories.

I am trying to build a function that shows what category a person is in based on the data they have put into excel. Right now, they enter their monthly sales into a field for each month. My formula would need to know what quarter it is, and the total they did for last quarter. If its the first quarter of the month, they would just start at GREEN.

I have been able to calculate the quarter totals for them, but I am getting stuck on this because my formula is getting massive.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the numbers they have to hit are listed in cells as well. So I can reference those.

Example:

```
Enter monthly sales:
  A       B        C   
1 Jan     Feb      Mar 
2 $10,000 $15,000  $20,000
3
4 Your current level is: GREEN
5
6 GOALS
7 Platinum   $100,000
8 Gold       $75,000
```

Here is how I am getting my quarter totals:

```
=IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=1,SUM(F5:H5)-D14,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=‌​2,SUM(I5:K5)-D14,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=3,SUM(L5:N5)-D14,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH‌​(TODAY())/3,0)=4,SUM(O5:Q5)-D14))))
```

[image]

If this helps, this is basically what I am going for, but its not working for me:

> =IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=1, “GREEN”, IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=2, IF(SUM(F5:H5) >= D14, “PLATINUM”,
>   IF(SUM(F5:H5) >= D15, “GOLD”, IF(SUM(F5:H5) >=D16, “GREEN”,
>   IF(SUM(F5:H5) >=D17, “GREEN”, IF(SUM(F5:H5)>=D18, “RED”,
>   IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=3, IF(SUM(I5:K5) >= D14, “PLATINUM”,
>   IF(SUM(I5:K5) >= D15, “GOLD”, IF(SUM(I5:K5) >=D16, “GREEN”,
>   IF(SUM(I5:K5) >=D17, “GREEN”, IF(SUM(I5:K5)>=D18, “RED”,
>   IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=4, IF(SUM(L5:N5) >= D14, “PLATINUM”,
>   IF(SUM(L5:N5) >= D15, “GOLD”, IF(SUM(L5:N5) >=D16, “GREEN”,
>   IF(SUM(L5:N5) >=D17, “GREEN”, IF(SUM(L5:N5)>=D18,
>   “RED”)))))))))))))))))))

Comment: We might need to see your formula.

Comment: `IF(SUM(A2:C2)>100000,"Platnum",IF(SUM(A2:C2)>75000,"Gold",IF(SUM(A2:C2)>50000,"Green",IF(SUM(A2:C2)>25000,"Yellow","Red"))))`  you can put cell references in place of numbers. `IF(SUM(A2:C2)>100000,B7,...`

Comment: Here is how I am getting my quarter totals:   =IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=1,SUM(F5:H5)-D14,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=2,SUM(I5:K5)-D14,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=3,SUM(L5:N5)-D14,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)=4,SUM(O5:Q5)-D14))))

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes but I need it to know what the current date is, and based the totals off the last quarter - thats the part I cant figure out. I was trying to do that without duplicating the function 4 times.

Comment: We will need a lot more info.  show a picture of you actual sheet.

Comment: one tip is to use a lookup table for Qtrs `... Jan | Q1 <br> Feb | Q1 <br> Mar | Q1 <br> Apr | Q2 ...` If you use some lookup tables to organize things a bit that can make your formula writing easier. You can also make a lookup table for levels as well.

Comment: Picture uploaded - thanks guys.

Comment: I would consider a pivot table with a cumulative value field. You could then use that as the source for your calculations.

Comment: pls try this formula (worked for me): `=CHOOSE(IF(MONTH(TODAY())<4,3,COUNTIF(D14:D18,"<="&SUM(OFFSET(F5,0,TRUNC(MONTH(TODAY())/3-1)*3,1,3))))+1,"below red","red","yellow","green","gold","platin")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a slight tweak so your sheet looks like this:

```
Enter monthly sales:
  A       B        C   
1 Jan     Feb      Mar 
2 $10,000 $15,000  $20,000
3 $45,000
4 Your current Q1 level is: GREEN
5
6 GOALS
7 Platinum   $100,000
8 Gold       $75,000
```

In A3 your formula would be:

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())<4,SUM(A2:C2),IF(MONTH(TODAY())<7,SUM(D2:F2),IF(MONTH(TODAY())<10,SUM(G2:I2),SUM(J2:L2))))
```

In A4 your formula would be:

```
=CONCATENATE("Your current ", IF(MONTH(TODAY())<4, "Q1", IF(MONTH(TODAY())<7, "Q2", IF(MONTH(TODAY())<10, "Q3","Q4"))), " level is: ", IF(A3<B8, "Green", IF(A3<B7, A8, IF(A3>B7, A7, "Error"))))
```

Comment: I think this is going to work - trying to adapt it to my spreadsheet now.

Comment: @MikeDavis A8 and A7 are the locations of the text "Platinum" or "Gold".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture and the fact that you already did all the calculation to find the value for the quarter use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"Platnum","Gold","Green","Yellow"},MATCH(TRUE,O8:O12>0,0)),"RED")
```

It is an array formula confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Change the range `O8:O12` to the range that has the amount remaining.  It will adjust as the levels are met.

It basically finds the first positive number and picks that color from the list.  If no numbers are above 0 or only the first it returns "Red"

Comment: @MikeDavis sorry forgot to add that is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  I edited to add that fact.

Comment: Hey Scott thanks again for your answer. Just to clarify - the "Level" that they are in is based on the results from their last quarter, rather than current. The red / green numbers I have in there are for their current quarter. Hope that makes sense. So that is what they have left to meet a certain goal for the future, but I am trying to show what they are at right now, based on what they did last quarter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can get you what you are after in a much simpler way:

I made a very crude version of your spreadsheet below. Please see the explanation for how it I made it work using built-in formulas. You can apply the same concepts to your exact spreadsheet by adjusting the cell references.

[image]

1. In D7 the formula is `=EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),1,1)-1,1)`
2. In E7-O7 the formula is `=EOMONTH(D7,1)`
3. You can format these dates to appear as you have them as `MMMM`
4. I labeled each month with a Qtr. You can make these white font so they are not visible to the user.
5. Cell D18 formula is `=TODAY()`
6. Cell D19 formula is `=OFFSET(C6,0,MATCH(MONTH(D18),MONTH(D7:O7),0))`. **It is entered as an Array formula, so press Ctrl + Alt + Enter after typing it in.**
7. Cell D16 formula is `=IF(SUMIF(D6:O6,D19,D8:O8)=0,"Green",VLOOKUP(SUMIF(D6:O6,D19,D8:O8),G16:H20,2,1))`

You probably combine these formulas into fewer cells, but I wanted to be able to demonstrate how everything was calculating. You can also leave it as is or just place white font for certain "working" cells that you don't want to be visible.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, this is what databases are good at ... but ok, that can be hard, so I will try to answer:

I would use the function VLOOKUP with the last parameter (range_lookup) omitted. This way you have to specify a table with the lower limit for each category (the upper limit is the next)

[image: Usage of VLOOKUP for ranges]

You might want to add an IF statement for the first month, but I don't have enough information to make that up for you, and it's not that hard

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to use the VLOOKUP command now to see if it will accomplish what I need.